# Doubts in integration with PHPExcel and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I'm with a doubt at this post:

http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrateload-phpexcel-into-codeigniter-framework/

I've done up to libraries part (Excel.php).

But in the tutorial, where it starts Example Usage, where exactly I need to put all that code? In a new controller? Here in my project I tried  to create a new Controller called Report. In report I've this code:

```
public function readReport() {
        $this->load->library('excel');
        $this->excel=PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(APPPATH."/third_party/teste.xlsx");
        $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        //get some value from a cell
        $number_value= $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C1')->getValue();
        $data['header'] = $number_value;
        $this->load->view('pages/home', $data);
    }
```

But I have also a Pages controller to control the pages of Views, and when I try to output something of PHP Excel is not possible. In my Pages.php I've wrote: $data['header'] = $number_value; and in view . But the variable "number_value" is not in Pages.php because it's only at Report.php. How can I do to output the excel data at my home.php (view) correctly?

Here is my pages.php controller

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {
    public function view ($page = 'home') {
        if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')) {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = str_replace("_", " ", $page);
        $data['header'] = $number_value;

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with PHPExcel but here are some thoughts.

First, to use a library in a Controller it must be loaded in that controller. You cannot access one controller from another. You could duplicate the code from `Report` in `Pages` but that seems a waste. You need reuseable code.

One "reuseable" approach is to create a model that uses the `excel` library. This will make it easy to reuse PHPExcel code just by loading the model in any controller.

A model version including a `readReport()` function might look like this.

```
class excel_model extends CI_Model
{
  protected $excel;

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('excel');
  }

  function readReport()
  {
    $this->excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(APPPATH."/third_party/teste.xlsx");
    $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    //get some value from a cell
    return $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C1')->getValue();
  }
}
```

`Pages` controller should be modified as follows.

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller
{
  public function view($page = 'home')
  {
    //The following check isn't needed, codeigniter will do this automatically
    //if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')) {
    //show_404();
    //}
    $this->load->model('excel_model');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $data['title'] = str_replace("_", " ", $page);
    $data['header'] = $this->excel_model->readReport();
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    //You don't have to keep sending $data to the views because 
    //any variables loaded by the first call to load->view()
    //will be visible the all other views loaded in this function.
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
  }

}
```

Comment: Man I have no word to thank you. It worked just perfect. Also thank you so much for the tips in my code!